# Why is a HyperLink's NavigateUrl a string not a uri?

Tags: vb.net

I have some code for setting the NavigateUrl property on a HyperLink using a function:

```
hypExtErrorReporting.NavigateUrl = ErrorReportingURL()
Public Function ErrorReportingURL() As String
  ' create the url and returns it as a string
End Function
```

Running FxCop highlights (amonst other things) CA1055 `The name of a method contains "uri", "Uri", "urn", "Urn", "url", or "Url", and the method returns a string.`

Conceptually this makes sense to me, if a function is returning a url/uri then return a uri not a string. But this means my code becomes

```
hypExtErrorReporting.NavigateUrl = ErrorReportingURL().ToString()
Public Function ErrorReportingURL() As Uri
  ' create the url and returns it as a string
End Function
```

Why does NavigateUrl take a string not a uri?

Comment: You can assign the value also on aspx where everything is a string

Comment: I'm pretty sure properties of a control need to be simple. Or else you'll need to add a bunch of extra tag in the aspx page. Something like: <asp:HyperLink><NavigateUrl url="..."></navigateUrl></asp:HyperLink>  Also, it allows you to put the tilde ~ or ../ which I don't think the URI class support.

Comment: But they have properties like `BackColor` which is of type Drawing.Color, so they are not all strings.

Comment: interesting point on the use of tilde, but that seems more of an 'addon' functionality rather than core, and if they wanted they could have made uri support tilde

Comment: Would be hard since uri is used for all type of application, not just web. It doesn't know which webpage you are on. It need a full url with domain name to work. Can't do "../test.htm" as a uri, but it's possible as an href.